# Combine multiple tables into one table by matching the headers

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables with the same header name. From this table I want to combine the data into one into one table by matching the header names.

The matching header names are **"Link", "Review Date", "Review Author", "Review Remarks"**.

The logic to combine data with these conditions that I catch like this:

Search for column positions with a combination of **REGEXMATCH**:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH('Multiple Table'!A2:Z2,"Link|Review\sDate|Review\sAuthor|Review\sRemarks")=TRUE,COLUMN('Multiple Table'!A2:Z2),""))
```

Change the column into a range with **ADDRESS** formula :

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH('Multiple Table'!A2:Z2,"Link|Review\sDate|Review\sAuthor|Review\sRemarks")=TRUE,ADDRESS(2,COLUMN('Multiple Table'!A2:Z2)),""))
```

I want the result from point 2 are **A2:D, F2:H**

Then to combine the data just enter the range **A2:D** and **F2:D** into the **QUERY** formula.

For the third step, I'm still confused about the formulation.

So I used a formula that wasn't dynamic yet, like this:

```
= QUERY ({'Multiple Tables'! A2: D; 'Multiple Tables'! F2: H}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 <> ''")
```

[Spreadsheet File.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xJNehwUHf3shpxx0X51_escvHsLe0CCrDf5QCayGeb4/edit#gid=1975911027)

Comment: Looking at your sheet, it looks like you already solved this. *"I used a formula that wasn't dynamic yet"*. If not, I fail to understand  what the question is.

Comment: I want use dynamic formula. Combine multiple table into one table by matching header name (without i put manually of range).

Comment: scenario like that :
=QUERY({get range contains header name as "Link", "Review Date", "Review Author", "Review Remarks"},"select A, B, C, D WHERE A<>''")

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But. I still cannot understand it. Sorry. Is it the rows that you have as `not correct` and `skip` that you do not want?

Comment: no.the data in status column no need to combine it

Answer (score 0):

try:
`={query(A2:E10,"select *");query(F3:J10,"select *",0)}`